# List all tables in order to perform analyze of all the tables

Tags: liquibase

I need to perform ANALYZE on the tables in the DB using liquibase.

The idea is that after I create and insert data to the tables via liquibase, I need to perform the ANALYZE command for PostgreSQL optimizer to know the count and distribution of data in the tables.
I know I can call a sql file usign the "sqlFile dbms" tag, and put all the analyze commands with the tables names hard coded in that file, but then of course if another table will be created, it will not be included in that file.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to analyze all tables, you don't have to list them. Running `analyze` will simply analyze all tables in the database.

So you can use a `<sql>` change to do that:

```
<changeSet author="tamar" id="1" runAlways="true" dbms="postgresql" runInTransaction="false">
  <sql>vacuum analyze</sql>
</changeSet>
```